# Pass vector as pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a vector of float

```
vector<float>nFloats;
```

I would like to pass it to the following function:

```
/* This is a non-stream oriented interface to just change the speed of a sound sample */
int sonicChangeFloatSpeed(
    float *samples,
    int numSamples,
    float speed,
    float pitch,
    float rate,
    float volume,
    int useChordPitch,
    int sampleRate,
    int numChannels)
{
    sonicStream stream = sonicCreateStream(sampleRate, numChannels);

    sonicSetSpeed(stream, speed);
    sonicSetPitch(stream, pitch);
    sonicSetRate(stream, rate);
    sonicSetVolume(stream, volume);
    sonicSetChordPitch(stream, useChordPitch);
    sonicWriteFloatToStream(stream, samples, numSamples);
    sonicFlushStream(stream);
    numSamples = sonicSamplesAvailable(stream);
    sonicReadFloatFromStream(stream, samples, numSamples);
    sonicDestroyStream(stream);
    return numSamples;
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to do it correctly?

My attempts

```
 1) int iRet = sonicChangeFloatSpeed(&nFloats[0], *num, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 48000, 1);

 2) int iRet = sonicChangeFloatSpeed(nFloats[0], *num, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 48000, 1);

 3) int iRet = sonicChangeFloatSpeed(*nFloats, *num, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 48000, 1);
```

all don't work.

I'm sure such a question has already been asked, but I couldn't find any exact duplicate.

Can anybody help?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the pointer is used as output of the function. You must `resize()` the vector before using it to an appropriate buffer size.

Comment: The semantics of the function are unclear, because it takes numSamples *and* returns it.

Comment: Is the function supposed to add floats to the vector? And what do you mean by `all don't work` ? Doesn't work in which way? The first method looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your first version should work, because the vectors use contiguous storage locations for their elements.

```
int iRet = sonicChangeFloatSpeed(&nFloats[0], nFloats.size(), 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 48000, 1);
```

In c++11 you can use

```
float* p = nFloats.data();
int iRet = sonicChangeFloatSpeed(p, nFloats.size(), 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 48000, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your approach is problematic.

Your function seems to do 2 things:

1) Write a number of floats to a stream

2) Read a number of floats from a stream

In both cases you want the floats to be in a `vector`.

For number 1 it is fine to use a `vector` but for number 2 it is very problematic.

You can't pass a pointer to the data held by a vector and then change the number of elements. The original vector will keep its original size. If you attempt to read more floats from the stream than currently held by the vector, the behavior is undefined.